# Adopting UIKeyInput protocol to get input from a Bluetooth keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, subclass

I have a Bluetooth foot switch that's basically a wireless keyboard.  One pedal sends the up arrow key, the other sends the down arrow key.  I want to be able to execute my own code in my iPad app when one of the pedals is pressed.  The maker of the pedal tells me I should create a `UITextField`, and adopt the `UIKeyInput` protocol in the containing UIView and use the `beginningOfDocument` and `endOfDocument` methods to execute my code.  I did this, but no matter what I do, none of the UIKeyInput or UITextInput methods get called.  Can anyone walk me through this, or direct me to a tutorial on something similar to this?  Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Here's my .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Pedal_ProtocolViewController : UIViewController <UIKeyInput, UITextInput>{
UITextField *myTextField;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
@end
```

And here's my .m:

```
#import "Pedal_ProtocolViewController.h"

@implementation Pedal_ProtocolViewController

@synthesize myTextField;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[myTextField canBecomeFirstResponder];
[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIKeyInput Protocol Methods

- (BOOL)hasText {
    return NO;
}

- (void)insertText:(NSString *)theText {
}

- (void)deleteBackward {
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES; 
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITextInput Protocol Methods

- (NSString *)textInRange:(UITextRange *)range {
    return @"";
}
- (void)replaceRange:(UITextRange *)range withText:(NSString *)text {
}
- (void) setSelectedTextRange: (UITextRange *) range {
}
- (UITextRange *) markedTextRange {
    return nil;
}
- (NSDictionary *) markedTextStyle {
    return nil;
}
- (void) setMarkedTextStyle: (NSDictionary *) style {
}
- (void)setMarkedText:(NSString *)markedText selectedRange:(NSRange)selectedRange {
}
- (void) unmarkText {
}
- (UITextPosition *) endOfDocument {
    //DOWN KEY

    NSLog(@"Down");
    return nil;
}
- (UITextPosition *) beginningOfDocument {
    //UP KEY

    NSLog(@"UP");
    return nil;
}
- (UITextRange *)textRangeFromPosition:(UITextPosition *)fromPosition toPosition:(UITextPosition *)toPosition{
    return nil;
}
- (UITextPosition *)positionFromPosition:(UITextPosition *)position offset:(NSInteger)offset{
    return nil;
}
- (UITextPosition *)positionFromPosition:(UITextPosition *)position inDirection:(UITextLayoutDirection)direction offset:(NSInteger)offset {
    return nil;
}
- (NSComparisonResult) comparePosition: (UITextPosition *)position toPosition: (UITextPosition *)other {
    return NSOrderedSame;
}
- (NSInteger) offsetFromPosition: (UITextPosition *)from toPosition: (UITextPosition *)toPosition {
    return 0;
}
- (void) setInputDelegate: (id <UITextInputDelegate>) delegate {
}
- (id <UITextInputDelegate>) inputDelegate {
    return nil;
}
- (id <UITextInputTokenizer>) tokenizer {
    return nil;
}
- (UITextPosition *)positionWithinRange:(UITextRange *)range farthestInDirection:(UITextLayoutDirection)direction {
    return nil;
}
- (UITextRange *) characterRangeByExtendingPosition: (UITextPosition *) position inDirection: (UITextLayoutDirection) direction {
    return nil;
}
- (UITextWritingDirection) baseWritingDirectionForPosition: (UITextPosition *)position inDirection: (UITextStorageDirection)direction {
    return 0;
}
- (void) setBaseWritingDirection: (UITextWritingDirection)writingDirection forRange:(UITextRange *)range {
}
- (CGRect) firstRectForRange: (UITextRange *) range {
    return CGRectZero;
}
- (CGRect) caretRectForPosition: (UITextPosition *) position  {
    return CGRectZero;
}
- (UITextPosition *) closestPositionToPoint: (CGPoint)point {
    return nil;
}
- (UITextPosition *) closestPositionToPoint: (CGPoint)point withinRange: (UITextRange *) range {
    return nil;
}
- (UITextRange *) characterRangeAtPoint: (CGPoint)point {
    return nil;
}
- (UITextRange *) selectedTextRange {
    return [[UITextRange alloc]init];
}

@end
```

Comment: I have the same problem now, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: There's some useful tidbits to be had in the [DCIntrospect project](https://github.com/0xced/DCIntrospect/blob/80425e50bbd7f779a42f009b93b0c1ef006946e9/DCIntrospect/DCIntrospect.m) over on Github. Those guys're using some neat selection tracking to distinguish between up, down, left, right, and all four with either shift and option, as well. All up, a pretty damn impressive effort, I thought.

Answer (score 6):

You have adopted the `UIKeyInput` in the `UIViewController`. Note the inheritance definition you entered:

```
@interface Pedal_ProtocolViewController : UIViewController <UIKeyInput, UITextInput>{
```

You've said here "This is a view controller that implements `UIKeyInput` and `UITextInput`." These two protocols apply to `UIResponder` subclasses such as `UIView` and subclasses or `UIView`. `UIViewController` is <strike>not one such class</strike> perhaps not the best class to handle text input.

View controllers manage views. They are not views themselves.

You can (instead of text input protocols) just use a hidden text field (such as the one you already have). Just create a subclass of `NSObject`  that implements a delegate for the text field, and assign it as the delegate of the text field. Then, in `-viewDidAppear:`, call `-becomeFirstResponder` on the text field to focus on the field. You can probably use some hack to hide the keyboard.

This approach was commonly used in games and game-supporting libraries to show the software keyboard. It even works on iOS 3.1.3 and earlier (which is not a problem for you, considering that you are developing for the iPad).

---

In case you will keep that design (handling input in the view controller), then this may be required and make it work.

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Do consider using the `UITextField` and a delegate for handling input, or implementing the above two functions and the `UIKeyInput` protocol in a subclass of `UIView`.

Also note you are not required to conform to `UITextInput` just to get keypresses; `UIKeyInput` is enough.

---

Additional note: if you decide to subclass `UIView` (which, along with using a hidden `UITextField`, is what I do; I haven't tried subclassing `UIViewController` to get keyboard input), you will want to add `-becomeFirstResponder` to `-awakeFromNib` instead:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

That's if you're loading the `UIViewController` (and hence the `UIView`) from a nib. Not doing that? Try adding that in `-initWithFrame:`:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGFrame)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(!self)
        return nil;

    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    return self;
}
```

Alternatively, in UIViewController's `viewDidLoad`:

```
    // ...
    [self.view becomeFirstResponder];
    // ...
```

There's obviously loads of ways you can do this. ;)

Comment: Actually, `UIViewController` is a subclass of `NSResponder`. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: UIResponder. Well, my bad :) I'm not sure it should become the first responder however. But it looks like that's what the question asker did not do. I'll update my answer.

Comment: The catch, though, is that I don't believe that a view controller can become the first responder, so you probably will still need to subclass `UIView`, but you'll also explicitly have to make it the first responder to trigger the keyboard functionality.

Comment: When I saw your comment, that's the first thing that came through my mind, "a view controller probably cannot be a first responder". But, I think that the only check UIKit does is asking a `UIResponder` whether it can become a first responder. Without testing, I believe the above solution (overriding `-canBecomeFirstResponder`, which is needed for `UIView` as well) should be correct. Also, slightly updating the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm enough of a nerd I went and tested it. I couldn't get the view controller to become first responder, but a UIView subclass worked as expected.

Comment: I was able to get the view controller to become a first responder by adding the canBeFirstResponder and calling becomeFirstResponder in the viewDidLoad class.  I can receive text just fine via the UIKeyInput protocol.

Answer (score 2):

See the solution I came up with for responding to arrow keys from a foot pedal:

[How can I respond to external keyboard arrow keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980447/how-can-i-respond-to-external-keyboard-arrow-keys/8036524#8036524)

Answer (score 2):

in IOS 7 it is easy. In previous versions - not official. Can be removed from App Store.

```
-(NSArray * ) keyCommands {
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] intValue] <7) return nil;
    UIKeyCommand *upArrow = [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput: UIKeyInputUpArrow modifierFlags: 0 action: @selector(upArrow:)];
    UIKeyCommand *downArrow = [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput: UIKeyInputDownArrow modifierFlags: 0 action: @selector(downArrow:)];
    UIKeyCommand *leftArrow = [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput: UIKeyInputLeftArrow modifierFlags: 0 action: @selector(leftArrow:)];
    UIKeyCommand *rightArrow = [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput: UIKeyInputRightArrow modifierFlags: 0 action: @selector(rightArrow:)];
    UIKeyCommand *escapeCom = [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:UIKeyInputEscape modifierFlags:0 action:@selector(escapeChar:)];
    return [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: upArrow, downArrow, leftArrow, rightArrow, escapeCom, nil];
}
```

It works for me, hope will be useful for you. Added version check to avoid usage in non-iOS7 devices.